# asp.net: RegisterStartupScript from ScriptManagerProxy, possible?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I need to run some javascript after an update panel updates, this update panel is in a Usercontrol located in a page that has a MasterPage. The MasterPage has a ScriptManager and the Usercontrol has a ScriptManagerProxy.

in the UserControl I am calling:

ScriptManagerProxyControl.Page.RegisterStartupScript(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('hello');");

but nothing is happening.

All the exmaples I see use ScriptManager, but this is not available as its on the master page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this codeproject article that solves my problem.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/hourglassajax.aspx